# What is the difference between Android and Androidx Packages in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-package-managers

I am new in mobile development using Java and Kotlin, I had an application in Java which I needed to start in a new project.
When creating a new project in Android Studio, I checked `Use androidx.* artifacts`. After coping some dependencies from my old project, I had too many errors which I fixed by going to `Refactor => Migrate to AndroidX`

Now I want to now what is the difference between `android` and `androidx` packages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has been building up APIs that are backward compatable and has a lot of Android Support libraries that exist in developer APIs. To clean up this mess,Android introduced androidx libraries. AndroidX is a major improvement to the original Android Support Library. Like the Support Library, AndroidX ships separately from the Android OS and provides backwards-compatibility across Android releases. AndroidX fully replaces the Support Library by providing feature parity and new libraries
You can read about androidx here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx